# Why am I not able to open open XML (generated in Ruby on Rails) using Excel software?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, openxml

I used an `xlsx.erb` template in my Rails application to generate an Excel report (as office XML). The excel file generates fine but I get an error while opening it in Excel software (`extension or file format maybe be invalid`)

This is the template I used to generate the open xml excel:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Worksheet ss:Name="Forecast">
<Names>
<NamedRange ss:Name="Print_Area"/>
</Names>
<Table>
  <Row>
    <% (1..5).each do |dayi| %>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= 'Day' + dayi.to_s %></Data><NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
    <% end %>

    <Cell/>

    <% (25..30).each do |i| %>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= 'NP' + i.to_s %></Data></Cell>
    <% end %>
  </Row>

  <% (1..5).each do |rowi| %>
    <Row>
      <% (1..5).each do |ci| %>
        <Cell><Data><%= ci %></Data><NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
      <% end %>

      <Cell/>

      <% (25..30).each do |i| %>
        <Cell><Data><%= i %></Data></Cell>
      <% end %>
    </Row>
  <% end %>
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

This is the open XML that got generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Forecast">
  <Names>
   <NamedRange ss:Name="Print_Area"/>
  </Names>
    <Table>
      <Row>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">Day1    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">Day2    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">Day3    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">Day4    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">Day5    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>

        <Cell/>

          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">NP25    </Data>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">NP26    </Data>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">NP27    </Data>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">NP28    </Data>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">NP29    </Data>    </Cell>
          <Cell>    <Data ss:Type="String">NP30    </Data>    </Cell>
      </Row>

        <Row>
            <Cell>    <Data>1    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>2    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>3    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>4    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>5    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>

          <Cell/>

            <Cell>    <Data>25    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>26    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>27    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>28    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>29    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>30    </Data>    </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>    <Data>1    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>2    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>3    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>4    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>5    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>

          <Cell/>

            <Cell>    <Data>25    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>26    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>27    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>28    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>29    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>30    </Data>    </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>    <Data>1    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>2    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>3    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>4    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>5    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>

          <Cell/>

            <Cell>    <Data>25    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>26    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>27    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>28    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>29    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>30    </Data>    </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>    <Data>1    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>2    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>3    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>4    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>5    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>

          <Cell/>

            <Cell>    <Data>25    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>26    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>27    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>28    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>29    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>30    </Data>    </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>    <Data>1    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>2    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>3    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>4    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>5    </Data>    <NamedCell
  ss:Name="pRange_default"/>    <NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/>    </Cell>

          <Cell/>

            <Cell>    <Data>25    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>26    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>27    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>28    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>29    </Data>    </Cell>
            <Cell>    <Data>30    </Data>    </Cell>
        </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Why am I not able to open the above open xml using Excel software?

Please help!

Comment: Is working here: Open Excel => Developer Tools => Import. This
is not working with standard open-dialogue.

Comment: I tried Excel -> Developer -> Import and selected the generated xlsx file. The file opens like shit - `ns1:Name ns1:Name2 ns1:Data ns1:Type ns1:Name3
Forecast Print_Area Day1 String pRange_default
Forecast Print_Area Day1 String Print_Area
Forecast Print_Area Day2 String pRange_default
Forecast Print_Area Day2 String Print_Area
Forecast Print_Area Day3 String pRange_default
`

Comment: I get a dump of the XML across columns in Excel instead of seeing actual Excel contents

Comment: `xlsx` is actually a zip file so you probably need to zip this although I have never tried to build the OpenXML schema by hand as that seems very tentative and tedious. There is a whole directory structure inside the zip file as well. Try it for your self take an xlsx and change the extension to .zip then explore the archive

Comment: @f6a4 Could you please explain what extenstion you save the XML as? Did you save it as file before importing it or .xlsx file? or was it some other extension?