# How to use Axlsx:NumFmt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formatting, axlsx

How do use Alxsx:NumFmt class?

I need to use this class to format currency values (positive and negative values)

I found some documentation for this class here - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/NumFmt

But there are no code samples available. Please help me on how to use this class.

Current Code:

```
currency_format_code = '$#,##0_;[Red]($#,##0_)' 
@default_style = wb.styles.add_style(:format_code => currency_format_code, 
  :sz => 10, :font_name => "Arial", 
  :alignment => {:horizontal => :right})
@italics_style = wb.styles.add_style(:format_code => currency_format_code, 
  :sz => 10, :font_name => "Arial Narrow", :i => true, 
  :alignment => {:horizontal => :right})

row_style = [nil, nil, nil, @default_left_style] + ([@default_style] * 25)

sheet.add_row[nil, nil, nil, day1, day2, day3, 
              day4, day5, day6, day7, day8, day9, 
              day10, day11, day12, day13, day14, 
              day15, day16, day17, day18, day19, 
              day20, day21, day22, day23, day24, 
              day25], :style => row_style
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The link that you just shared - that was also a question posted by me :) :)  I was applying formatting as shown in that question but when I did that for hundreds of cells, the performance went for a toss. So I was trying a different approach when I came across the class posted in this question, only I have no clue how to use this in code. Some code sample would really help...

Comment: Long story short - I would like to do exactly what is done in the other question of mine which you had pointed out - only I would like to do it using the class I mentioned in this question

Comment: Can you post the code you are using because there is no reason the formatting should be dragging down performance. I think the issue is that you are probably generating styles in a loop rather than generating 1 style and reusing it. That class is fairly internal and not something you really want to deal with directly.

Comment: So instead of doing formatting this way -> `wb.styles.add_style(:format_code => '[Gray][A6A6A6]$#,##0_;[Red]($#,##0_)')` , I would like to do the same formatting ( `$#,##0_;[Red]($#,##0_)')`) but using the class `Axlsx:NumFmt`

Comment: My point is if done correctly there is no need to use that class since what you will be defining there is not really going to do anything. Your issue is most likely that you are doing this `wb.styles.add_style(:format_code => '[Gray][A6A6A6]$#,##0_;[Red]($#,##0_)')` many times rather than doing it once and reusing it. If you would post the code I can help but right now showing you how to generate a `NumFmt` does not help since it won't be usable in the workbook

Comment: @engineersmnky - Thanks much for your inputs. This is how I am using it. I have declared 2 styles and I use these 2 styles in hundreds of records (each record having tens of cells). `currency_format_code = '$#,##0_;[Red]($#,##0_)'

  @default_style = wb.styles.add_style(:format_code => currency_format_code, :sz => 10, :font_name => "Arial", :alignment => {:horizontal => :right}) 
  @italics_style = wb.styles.add_style(:format_code => currency_format_code, :sz => 10, :font_name => "Arial Narrow", :i => true, :alignment => {:horizontal => :right})`

Comment: `row_style = [nil, nil, nil, @default_left_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style, @default_style]`

Comment: And then I use the `row_style` declared above in an `add_row`. `sheet.add_row[nil, nil, nil, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7, day8, day9, day10, day11, day12, day13, day14, day15, day16, day17, day18, day19, day20, day21, day22, day23, day24, day25], :style => row_style`

Comment: so I DO declare the style with the formatting in one place and then reuse it several hundred times but that still seems to slow down the Excel generation MULTIPLE times

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can make this more performant than what you already have. This issue is that the style is applied to each cell in the row individually [array_to_cells](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/row.rb#L148)

Excerpt:

```
def array_to_cells(values, options={})
  DataTypeValidator.validate :array_to_cells, Array, values
  types, style, formula_values = options.delete(:types), options.delete(:style), options.delete(:formula_values)
  values.each_with_index do |value, index|
    options[:style] = style.is_a?(Array) ? style[index] : style if style
    options[:type] = types.is_a?(Array) ? types[index] : types if types
    options[:formula_value] = formula_values[index] if formula_values.is_a?(Array)

    self[index] = Cell.new(self, value, options)
  end
end
```

So as you can see it loops through all 28 cells in the row  and looks up the style that should be applied for each then creates a new `Cell` with that style. Which is probably where the degradation is coming from.

Comment: Thanks much for your inputs - truly appreciate it! Actually to avoid this issue, I tried a completely different approach to generate Excel sheet - I tried generating Excel as an Open XML document. I was able to generate the document but was not able to open the generated document using MS Excel. Would you be able to help me with this please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416889/why-am-i-not-able-to-open-open-xml-generated-in-ruby-on-rails-using-excel-soft

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party: To use the [`NumFmt`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx%2FStyles:numFmts) numbers you add them to your style not using `format_code`, but the `num_fmt` option:

```
  number_style = p.workbook.styles.add_style({
    num_fmt: 2,
    alignment: { horizontal: :center, :vertical => :center},
    border: { color: "000000", style: :thin},
    bg_color: "F2F2F2"
  })
```